# Rails: change URL response format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How to easily change the format of URL in a right way:

```
/comment/10.js?param1=6
```

to

```
/comment/10?param1=6
```

Preferrably with some URL library or so, not with regexps.

Use case: redirect back with request.request_uri saved in session.

Comment: Not exactly sure what you are asking...  Change the way rails generates Urls via it's view_helpers? Change rails routes to treat /10?param as a .js format?  Manipulate existing URLs in some body of text to remove '.js'?  Please be more specific.

Comment: request.request_uri is stored into session with the value "/comment/10.js?param1=6". Then later I want to redirect back using redirect_to with the value stored, but I'm redirecting back not from js call, so need to remove .js.
Currently I just remove .js with regexps. I thought there might be some library or so for that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure the use case, but the simplest way would be in the controller

```
respond_to do |f|
  f.js { redirect_to #copy url params, but set :format to what you actually want }
end
```